# Why doesn't this code kill the process?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
Process.Start(jrekeypath);

Thread.Sleep(5);

foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith("javaw"))
    {
        clsProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```

It doesn't kill the process. Is there any problem in this snippet?

Comment: [Don't flag your question as “Urgent”, even if it is for you](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 ms is not an extremely long time. Could it be that the process has in fact not yet started when your code looks for it, but instead starts shortly afterwards?

Comment: I prefer Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan) over Thread.Sleep(int) to avoid this kind of confusion.  It's nice when sleep can be avoided all together...

Answer (score 10):

Ditto the 5ms answer above, but you could also try keeping the process handle around and re-using that, e.g.

```
var javawProcess = Process.Start(jrekeypath);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
javawProcess.Kill();
```